# Arbitrary precision decimals in C#?

Tags: c#, math

Is there an arbitrary-precision *decimal* class available for C#? I've seen a couple of arbitrary precision integer classes, but that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use J# library's `java.math.BigDecimal` class if you have it installed. Just add a reference to `vjslib`.

```
/me remembers one of the betas in which we had System.Numeric.BigDecimal, sigh
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Also, other constraints would prevent me from shipping a JDK with my product to be sure it worked! :)

Comment: J# library is not JDK. It's a .NET thing. There is a separate redist library however.