# How to get decimal to n places precision in C# program for Pi

Tags: c#, decimal, precision, pi

With reg to this question
[Pi in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395/how-do-i-calculate-pi-in-c)

I coded the below code and gives a output with last 6 digits as 0. So I want to improve the program by converting everything to decimal. I have never used decimal in C# instead of a double before and I am only comfortable with double in my regular use.

So please help me with decimal conversion, i tried to replace all double to decimal at start and it didnt turn good :(.

```
 using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(" Get PI from methods shown here");
    double d = PI();
    Console.WriteLine("{0:N20}",
        d);

    Console.WriteLine(" Get PI from the .NET Math class constant");
    double d2 = Math.PI;
    Console.WriteLine("{0:N20}",
        d2);
    }

    static double PI()
    {
    // Returns PI
    return 2 * F(1);
    }

    static double F(int i)
    {
    // Receives the call number
   //To avoid so error
    if (i > 60)
    {
        // Stop after 60 calls
        return i;
    }
    else
    {
        // Return the running total with the new fraction added
        return 1 + (i / (1 + (2.0 * i))) * F(i + 1);
    }
    }
}
```

Output

> Get PI from methods shown here
>   3.14159265358979000000  Get PI from the .NET Math class constant
>   3.14159265358979000000

Comment: Check out Eric Lippert's answer to a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107047/c-high-double-precision/4107225#4107225

Comment: @Justin, I dont want to change algorithm to Eric's. I am comfortable with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, replacing `double` with `decimal` is a good start - and then all you need to do is change the constant from 2.0 to 2.0m:

```
static decimal F(int i)
{
    // Receives the call number
    // To avoid so error
    if (i > 60)
    {
        // Stop after 60 calls
        return i;
    }
    else
    {
        // Return the running total with the new fraction added
        return 1 + (i / (1 + (2.0m * i))) * F(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Of course it's still going to have limited precision, but slightly more than `double`. The result is `3.14159265358979325010`.

Comment: Would you please explain the algorithm of Jon Skeet's solution.

Comment: @user2922935: It's the same algorithm as with the original code. All I've done is make the use of `decimal` consistent.