# C# unlimited significant decimal digits (arbitrary precision) without java

Tags: c#, decimal, fractions, decimal-point, arbitrary-precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the equivalent for java class : BigDecimal in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863388/what-is-the-equivalent-for-java-class-bigdecimal-in-c)

I know in this post: [Arbitrary precision decimals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621684/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c) says to use java.math.BigDecimal, but I don't have J# installed. How would I achieve arbitrary precision in C#? I was thinking of using binary strings but I may run into some trouble when multiplying the two.

Answer (score 1):

See [What is the equivalent of the Java BigDecimal class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863388/what-is-the-equivalent-for-java-class-bigdecimal-in-c)

You could create your own BigDecimal that used BigInteger under the covers and kept track of where the decimal point would need to be.

Comment: FYI: You have to add a reference to System.Numerics