# How to use math.round() in .net

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to round off below decimal number upto 4 decimal point. the below decimal no is

**1.0715086071862673E+301** but when i am using Math.Round function.it's not working and returning same above no.please let me know how to round this no.

```
**code here:**
double s=2.0;
double ku = Math.Pow(s, 1000);
double jlk = Math.Round(ku, 4);
```

here depending on my logic i need only **1.0715** number.

Comment: Where is the code? How did you specify the number? As a decimal, float,double or var? How did you call Math.Round? Are you sure you are checking the result of Math.Round instead of the original value?

Comment: that is quite a large number.  is that a long?

Comment: You can't change what's stored in the `double` variables - but you can control the number of digits shown when you convert it to a `string`.

Comment: this has got to be a string. a ulong would be 2^64, or 18446744073709551616 at max.

Comment: 2 to the power 1000 is 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376. What are you hoping to get as a result from the `Math.Round` call?

Comment: First, this is not rounding. Rounding is done after the decimal places. Since this is an integer, rounding it gives the same result as input. E.g. Round 10, result is 10. Round of 1000 is 1000 and so on.

Comment: nevermind.. this value can be a double +-1.7 E 308

Comment: The Dot within `1.07...` does not mean that you will round your number to 1! The important part is `E+301`, which shows you that your number `1.07..` will get multiplied with 100000... (301 zeros following after the 1). What did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you round it ? Its a whole number anyway.

```
using System;
// referencing System.Numerics.dll
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(2);
            bigInt = BigInteger.Pow(bigInt, 1000);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(bigInt.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Rounding a whole number results in a whole number. Maybe you were asked this question in an interview ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Double val = 1.0715086071862673E+301
Math.Round(val / (10 ^ 297), 0) * (10 ^ 297))
```

The answer is going to be 1.0715E+301 ...

---

if you want it to be 1.0715, you would do

```
Double val = 1.0715086071862673E+301
Math.Round(val / (10 ^ 297), 0)
```

---

### Additonally

This will work, but I wanted to point out that the conversion rounds in the process. (Also, this is vb.net - I'm not positive whether CType is how you convert in C#)

```
CType(CType((val / (10 ^ 297)) + 0.5, Long), Double) //Yields 1.0716
CType(CType((val / (10 ^ 297)), Long), Double)       //Yields 1.0715
```

Comment: And to get the 297 dynamically, one would use `Math.Floor(Math.Log10(val))-4`. Is `(10 ^ 297)` really what you think it is?

Comment: well.. it's 10 followed by 297 0's is about how I gauge it..

Thanks for the dynamic portion.. I didn't tackle it. I figured the OP was being a bit arbitrary on the whole precision aspect anyhow. rounding to the nearest 10^297 is one thing.. dropping a value by 10^297 is another.

Comment: As mathematical notation it is ok, and also in most CAS, but C like programming languages have ^ as bitwise "and", and script languages prefer x**y for the power operator.

Answer (score -1):

Use an appropriate type i.e. BigDecimal, src here [Arbitrary-Precision Decimals in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523741/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c-sharp/4524254#4524254)

Comment: Won't help. [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) range is -7.9 x 10^28 to 7.9 x 10^28. It won't be able to store a number up in the 10^301s