# How to return BigInteger from Math.Pow

Tags: c#, math, biginteger

I have the following function:

```
private static BigInteger Factorial(int number)
{
     if(number < 2) return BigInteger.One;
     double sum = 0;
     for(int i = 2; i < number; i++)
         sum += Math.Log(i);
     return new BigInteger(Math.Exp(sum));
}
```

This works fine for small input numbers like `10`, however if I pass a bigger number like `50000` it crashes and throws an `OverflowException`.

I understand why this is happening, the result of `Math.Exp(sum)` is just too big for a `double`. But that's why I'm trying to use `BigInteger` after all, to avoid these type of exceptions.

The problem is that wrapping the result like `new BigInteger(Math.Exp(sum))` is useless because `Map.Exp(sum)` is trying to return a `double` anyway.

So I decided to use `BigInteger.Pow` static function:

```
return BigInteger.Pow(new BigInteger(Math.E), number);
```

Note the `new BigInteger(Math.E)` part. `BigInteger.Pow` takes a `BigInteger` as the first parameter so I don't have a choice but to wrap my `Math.E` to a `BigInteger`.

However, by doing this I am actually truncating the decimal part of my `Math.E` which ruins my algorithm because I end up with a totally different result.

I was looking for something like `BigDouble` or something similar, but the only class that I seem to find is `BigInteger`.

How can I successfully return the correct result as a `BigInteger` on this function and at the same time have an exception-safe code when big input is received?

Comment: Do you need an accurate or an adducent value?

Comment: You will have to find a representation which can hold numbers like `50000!`. Nor `double` nor `BigInteger` is suitable. `BigInteger` can hold the result, but takes pretty much time (several secs) to calculate.

Comment: You could use the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4524254/916299) and add to it. Since they have already implemented multiplication, you can just multiply repeatedly to get powers

Comment: @hege_hegedus I really need the accurate value of `Math.E` for this algorithm to work properly. The result of `Math.Pow` or `Math.Exp` can be truncated though.

Comment: @JamesWebster I was really trying to avoid multiplication, but I'll take a look at it!

Comment: Powers are just multiplication.. Admittedly the compiler can usually make it a bit more efficient by reusing results

Comment: @hege_hegedus then how wolframalpha calculates something like [this](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5000000000000000%21&x=0&y=0)?

Comment: @hege_hegedus if one needs just occasionally compute 50000! several seconds may be ok (like `Enumerable.Range(1, 50000).Aggregate(new BigInteger(1), (i,f)=> i*f)` ). Not clear what OP is actually looking for so...

Comment: e is not a finite precision value, so you can't get a correct value this way. use otherways like table lookup and/or dynamic programming

Answer (score 1):

You could use base 2 instead of base *e*:

```
private static BigInteger FactorialEstimate(int number)
{
    if (number < 2) return BigInteger.One;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++)
        sum += Math.Log(i, 2);
    return BigInteger.Pow(2, (int)Math.Round(sum));
}
```

If you need a more accurate answer:

```
private static BigInteger NthRoot(BigInteger a, int n)
{
    BigInteger min = BigInteger.Zero, max = a, mid = a;
    while (min < max)
    {
        mid = (min + max) >> 1;
        if (BigInteger.Pow(mid, n) < a)
            min = mid + 1;
        else
            max = mid;
    }
    return max;
}

const int Accuracy1 = 16;
const int Accuracy2 = 8;
private static BigInteger FactorialBetterEstimate(int number)
{
    if (number < 2) return BigInteger.One;
    double sumFractPart = 0;
    int sumIntPart = 0, tmpIntPart = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++)
    {
        sumFractPart += Math.Log(i, 2);
        tmpIntPart = (int)sumFractPart;
        sumFractPart -= tmpIntPart;
        sumIntPart += tmpIntPart;
    }

    int correction = Math.Min(Accuracy2, sumIntPart);
    sumIntPart -= correction;
    sumFractPart += correction;

    return NthRoot(BigInteger.Pow(2, Convert.ToInt32(Accuracy1 * sumFractPart)), Accuracy1) << sumIntPart;
}
```

But you only gain considerable speedup at numbers like 100000 compared to the exact factorial function. And at that
scale all the functions get *really* slow.

Comment: I'd consider naming the function `FactorialLowEstimate` - using integer types frequently gives callers expectation of exact result which is clearly not the case in this computation.