# Using J# Redistributable in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, precision, bigdecimal

I'm trying to get an arbitrary-precision decimal class in C# as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523741/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c-sharp). I've downloaded and installed the J# re distributable, but I'm clueless as to how to import / reference it into my visual studio project. The folder it has created looks like the picture below, but none of these DLLs seem like the one I want to import in able to use the BigDecimal class. How do I use this class in my visual studio C# code?

EDIT: I have managed to reference the DLL but whenever I use the BigDecimal type I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: You need to run `install.exe` first and then you can refer assembly. Might be it automatically register that within GAC. But I'm not sure