# How to convert float or double to string

Tags: c#, string, double

i have a variable such this

```
double a=123456789012345678901234567890.1234567890123456;
```

i want to convert a(above variable) to string value in

```
console.writeline();
```

when i write

```
a.ToString();
```

i see the result as

```
1.23456789012346E+29
```

but only i want to have a varable such below.

```
string s="123456789012345678901234567890.1234567890123456";
```

how can i make s from a?

Comment: use a big decimal class?  https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigDecimal/

Comment: Maybe using a [custom/built-in format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Double_ToString_System_String_) will help?

Comment: duplicate of ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523741/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c-sharp/4524254#4524254

Comment: `double` has 64-bit length only; that's why *precision loss* is inevitable.

Comment: refer this format and simply apply https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Double_ToString_System_String_

Answer (score 1):

You can't, since `double` doesn't have such a high precision you can save the entire number into the `double`. (To see what part is actually saved, try `Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("n9"));`)

You have to use another data type that does support such high precision numbers, for example [`BigDecimal`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4523741/993547).