# Issue with large doubles turning negative when displaying

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a clicker game in un. Currently I am using doubles as a way to show large numbers. However when I get to any numbers above a trillion, it goes to -1354 trillion or something like that. The code shown bellow is code to fill in large numbers as "___ Million" or "____ Billion" but once it gets past 999 Billion is shows "-1354 Trillion". It continues to act like a trillion dollars, as you can buy items with apparently negative money, but the display is all wrong.

I have tried changing the double to int, long, and float and all of them result in the same issue. I have also tried even larger numbers but they don't even work in the system. It seems like 999 Billion is the limit before it turns all hell loose.

```
public static string largeWholeNumbers(double number)
{
    int numOfZeros = (number.ToString()).Length; //Gets Length of number
    int zeroSets = (int)Mathf.Floor(numOfZeros / 3.001f); //Divides it by a little over 3 and floors it 
    double numDisplay = number/(power(10, ((2 *zeroSets) + (zeroSets - 1)))); //Get the thing infront of the illion (IE 134, 6 million)

    //Defines
    string numberName = "";
    int hugeNumberSet = 0;
    int hugeNumberStart = 0;
    int hugeNumberStartIndex = 0;
    int hugeNumberEnd = 0;

    if (zeroSets < 11)
    {
        zeroSets -= 2;
        numberName = numberEndings.wholeNumEndings[zeroSets];
    }

    if (zeroSets > 10)
    {
        hugeNumberSet = (int)Mathf.Floor((zeroSets - 1)/10); //Divides it by 10 to get 10, 20, 30 etc
        hugeNumberEnd = hugeNumberSet - 1;
        hugeNumberStart = zeroSets - (hugeNumberSet * 10); //Example zeroSet = 12, this = 2
        hugeNumberStartIndex = hugeNumberStart - 1; 
        if (hugeNumberStart < 1)
        {
            numberName = numberEndings.endNumEndings[hugeNumberEnd];
        }

        if (hugeNumberStart >= 1)
        {
            numberName = numberEndings.endNumEndings[hugeNumberEnd] + numberEndings.beginNumEndings[hugeNumberStartIndex];
        }
    }

    return numDisplay.ToString() + " " + numberName;
}
```

Expected results would be to show the number in the interface as "1 Trillion", however it shows it as "-1354 Trillion".

Comment: AFAIK, all the existing numeric types do not fit requirements for clickers. You need to use some kind of long arithmetics, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: @rs232 depends the needs I'ld say .. [double](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.double.maxvalue) has a Max value that is quite ok for a while (depending ofcourse how fast you increase)

Comment: I suspect that your `power` function returns an int/long that is overflowing. Can you try `Mathf.pow()` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arbitrary-Precision Decimals in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523741/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Whole number is an integer right? Why do you use double for ints then? It's a waste of memory space.

Comment: Also converting double to string and back and forth is weird. There're too many possible tricks can cause an overflow.