# How to round the double values to remove the consecutive 9's or 0's

Tags: c#, double, rounding

how to round the below values to remove the consecutive 9's from a double value.
Significant digit rounding in .Net framework and .net core working differently.

Used the below code to round the double value to significant digits by passing the value 5.9E-12 and rounding to 12 significant digits

```
  private static double RoundToSignificantDigits(double d, int digits)
         {
             if (d == 0)
                 return 0;

              double scale = Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(d))) + 1);
              return scale * Math.Round(d / scale, digits);
         }
```

.Net core result : 5.8999999999999995E-12
.Net Framework Result : 5.9E-12

How to get the result like .Net framework in .Net core

Comment: if you want precice decimal value use `decimal` instead of `double`

Comment: decimal is the correct awnser, especially when handling currency

Comment: that number will vary at every point so we can't tell on up to what digits to be rounded

Comment: It's not a currency type I need to do very precise calculations and that some times be up to 20 decimal points

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) If you _need_ precision, take the performance hit and use decimal.

Comment: Then what are you hoping for when rounding the values? Values like `0.3` can not be correctly represented with binary floating-point nubmers

Comment: Problem is in .net Framework when I do multiplication I am getting 5.9E-12 and for the same multiplication, I am getting 5.8999999999999995E-12 in .Net Core. I just want it to be rounded like in .Net Framework

Comment: They are probably the same value but differently presented, where are you seeing the value? In the debugger or some output?

Comment: Also please show the relevant code.

Comment: Updated the question and added the Code

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear what exactly you want to achive. But you cannot represent any decimal number correctly as a `double` value.

Say you have a number `x`, it needs to hold to the following formula

```
x = n/m where n and m do not share any factor and m is a power of 2
```

to have a chance of being currectly represetable as double.

So the number `5.9E-12` is equal to `59/(10^13)`. You clearly see that `10^13` is not a power of 2 so `5.9E-12` can not corrctly represented as a double value

If you would do [`Console.WriteLine("{0:G17}", double.Parse("5.9E-12"));`](https://tio.run/##DYu9CsIwEIDn3FMcmVqwxQoi2lHERaHg4CAOMQ3hoE0glwpS8uwx6/ejudGsc16YnMXHj6OZe9CTYsYheBvUjLCC4Kgiafx6GvGuyFUcQzleb1TBco0gSiTO3rGfTPsMFM2NnKnkuj1du0OSGxz98iluUIEL37fHS9PtZF33IBKknP8) you would get the value `5.9000000000000003E-12` and not `5.9E-12`.

All this basicly araises for the same reason you cant write the decimal expansion of `1/3` or `1/7` to the end (without the periodical shortcut).

So if you want numbers that can be rounded to values that have a finite decimal expansion use `decimal` and not `double`.

Or you could create a Fractional Type based on `BitInteger` that would have an unlimited amount of precision. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523836/6560579) for a discussion.