# trying to adjust addition function to a subtraction function

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I have this function:

```
        static int[] AddArrays(int[] a, int[] b)
        {
            Array.Reverse(a);
            Array.Reverse(b);

            int[] result = new int[Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length) + 1];

            int carry = 0;
            int value = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length); ++i)
            {
                value = (i < a.Length ? a[i] : 0) + (i < b.Length ? b[i] : 0) + carry;

                result[i] = value % 10;
                carry = value / 10;
            }

            if (carry > 0)
                result[result.Length - 1] = carry;
            else
                Array.Resize(ref result, result.Length - 1);

            // Let's restore a and b
            Array.Reverse(a);
            Array.Reverse(b);

            Array.Reverse(result);

            return result;
        }
```

the function takes 2 arrays of digits these arrays represent a big number which is outside of the integer limits.
the function adds together the elements and returns the result.
my question is how can i adjust this function to subtract the numbers, for example:

input:

```
int[] a = 5,475,982,475,984,574,238,975,248,522,952,789,229,899,999,999,9

int[] b = 5,475,982,475,984,574,238,975,248,522,952,789,229,899,999,999,8
```

(as digit lists meaning each index in the arr is one digit)

expected output:
`1`
(since `5,475,982,475,984,574,238,975,248,522,952,789,229,899,999,999,9 - 5,475,982,475,984,574,238,975,248,522,952,789,229,899,999,999,8 = 1`)

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523741/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c-sharp)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most reliable methods should be to use the built in types, i.e. [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-7.0), for arbitrary precision math.

```
static int[] SubtractArrays(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    var bigA = new BigInteger(MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, byte>(a).ToArray());
    var bigB = new BigInteger(MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, byte>(a).ToArray());
    var bigC = bigA - bigB;

    return MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>(bigC.ToByteArray()).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that result is *not negative* (otherwise you should think over how to *represent* it as an array) you can modify the code into (same school algorithm but for *subtraction* now):

```
static int[] SubtractArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
  Array.Reverse(a);
  Array.Reverse(b);

  int[] result = new int[Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length)];
  int carry = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length); ++i) {
    int value = (i < a.Length ? a[i] : 0) - (i < b.Length ? b[i] : 0) - carry;

    if (value < 0) {
      value += 10;
      carry = 1;
    }
    else
      carry = 0;

    result[i] = value;
  }

  int size = result.Length;

  for (int i = result.Length - 1; i >= 1; --i)
    if (result[i] != 0)
      break;
    else
      size -= 1;

  Array.Resize(ref result, size);

  // Let's restore a and b
  Array.Reverse(a);
  Array.Reverse(b);
  Array.Reverse(result);

  return result;
}
```

Demo:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int[] a = "5,475,982,475,984,574,238,975,248,522,952,789,229,899,999,999,9"
  .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')
  .Select(c => c - '0')
  .ToArray();

int[] b = "5,475,982,475,984,574,238,975,248,522,952,789,229,899,999,999,8"
  .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')
  .Select(c => c - '0')
  .ToArray();

int[] c = SubtractArrays(a, b);

Console.Write(string.Concat(c));
```

Output:

```
1
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEfeqA)