# Is there a BigFloat class in C#?

Tags: c#, numeric, bigfloat

`System.Numerics.BigInteger` lets you multiply large integers together, but is there anything of the same type for floating point numbers? If not, is there a free library I can use?

```
//this but with floats
System.Numerics.BigInteger maxint = new BigInteger(int.MaxValue);

System.Numerics.BigInteger big = maxint * maxint * maxint;
System.Console.WriteLine(big);
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for a `BigRat`?

Comment: No, no standard `BigDecimal` either. :(  (but they got `Complex` covered, yay!)

Comment: @RandolphWest Double has the same limitations as `int`, albeit at a higher number.

Comment: @Cameron whats BigRat? got a link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating big float number fast like 0.4 ^ 100000000 ,, any ideas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738309/calculating-big-float-number-fast-like-0-4-100000000-any-ideas)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BigRational&referringTitle=Home)?  Microsoft released it under their BCL project on CodePlex.  Not actually sure how or if it will fit your needs.

It keeps it as a rational number.  You can get the a string with the decimal value either by casting or some multiplication.

```
var r = new BigRational(5000, 3768);
Console.WriteLine((decimal)r);
Console.WriteLine((double)r);
```

Or with a simple(ish) extension method like this:

```
public static class BigRationalExtensions
{
    public static string ToDecimalString(this BigRational r, int precision)
    {
        var fraction = r.GetFractionPart();

        // Case where the rational number is a whole number
        if(fraction.Numerator == 0 && fraction.Denominator == 1)
        {
            return r.GetWholePart() + ".0";
        }

        var adjustedNumerator = (fraction.Numerator
                                           * BigInteger.Pow(10, precision));
        var decimalPlaces = adjustedNumerator / fraction.Denominator;

        // Case where precision wasn't large enough.
        if(decimalPlaces == 0)
        {
            return "0.0";
        }

        // Give it the capacity for around what we should need for 
        // the whole part and total precision
        // (this is kinda sloppy, but does the trick)
        var sb = new StringBuilder(precision + r.ToString().Length);

        bool noMoreTrailingZeros = false;
        for (int i = precision; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if(!noMoreTrailingZeros)
            {
                if ((decimalPlaces%10) == 0)
                {
                    decimalPlaces = decimalPlaces/10;
                    continue;
                }

                noMoreTrailingZeros = true;
            }

            // Add the right most decimal to the string
            sb.Insert(0, decimalPlaces%10);
            decimalPlaces = decimalPlaces/10;
        }

        // Insert the whole part and decimal
        sb.Insert(0, ".");
        sb.Insert(0, r.GetWholePart());

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

If it's out of the precision range of a decimal or double, they will be cast to their respective types with a value of 0.0.  Also, casting to decimal, when the result is outside of its range, will cause an `OverflowException` to be thrown.

The extension method I wrote (which may not be the *best* way to calculate a fraction's decimal representation) will accurately convert it to a string, with unlimited precision.  However, if the number is smaller than the precision requested, it will return 0.0, just like decimal or double would.

Comment: it keeps the answer in rational form? can you get a decimal out of it? This might work. thanks for the link

Comment: I'm using some pretty giant numbers, but both your ways to convert it are giving me zero's

Comment: @jb. - Sorry it took me so long, but I've finally got it figured out.  My new extension method will convert any BigRational number to a decimal string properly.  It was a little more complicated than I hoped it would be, and I'm *positive* that there is either a faster or easier way of doing this.  However, I'm no mathematician, so I think it's safe to say I have no idea what I'm doing.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It should be considered what the implications would be if there were a `BigFloat` type.

```
BigFloat x = 1.0;
BigFloat y = 3.0;
BigFloat z = x / y;
```

The answer would be `0.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333` recurring. Forever. Infinite. Out of Memory Error.

It is easy to construct an infinite `BigFloat`.

However, if you are happy to stick to rational numbers, those express by the dividing one integer with another than you can use `BigInteger` to build a `BigRational` type that can provide arbitrary precision for representing any real number.

```
BigRational x = 1;
BigRational y = 3;
BigRational z = x / y;
```

This works and gives us this type:

[image: One Third]

You can just NuGet `BigRational` and you'll find many implementations, including once from Microsoft.

Comment: To avoid the possible OOM, it seems it would be possible to 'lazy calculate' the result in such a way that it would only calculate enough digits that are being asked for.