# c# Floating-point constant is outside the range of type 'decimal'

Tags: c#

I add some numbers in google calc and it gave me 8.5070592e+37

```
decimal uhoh = 8.5070592e+37M;
```

> Floating-point constant is outside the range of type 'decimal'

How can I parse this? I tried using `IntXLib`, but I cannot see how to pass this format, I also hear about `BigInteger`, please advice how to fix the problem.

EDIT:

9,223,372,036,854,775,807 * 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 =8.5070592e+37

How do I get the full number, for example, the number

> 328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425328574893257893425893783934534253285748932578934258937839345342532857489325789342589378393453425

or whatever that actually equals?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "pass" and where is your float error coming from? On the definition itself?

Comment: Are you coding in mathematica  as well or just using the output from it?

Comment: For a value of that size, do you really want `decimal`? The compiler is telling you pretty clearly: it's outside the range of `decimal`. You haven't really given us enough information about what you're trying to do - maybe `BigInteger` is appropriate, or maybe `double` is. It depends on your situation.

Comment: cannot convert from 'double' to 'int'

Comment: `decimal.MaxValue` is `79228162514264337593543950335m`. So, your `uhoh` value is tooooo big for a decimal.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. "How can I parse this?" and "but I cannot see how to pass this format" doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: use this to solve your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359372/is-there-a-bigfloat-class-in-c