# Round to the nearest whole number

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I have a number like this: `1.79769313486232E+308` and I want to round it to the nearest whole number. so I tried the below one:

```
Math.Round(1.79769313486232E+308, 0)
```

But it still give the same result.

Can any one help me.?

Comment: does this work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359372/is-there-a-bigfloat-class-in-c

Comment: That number seems way to large to fit into a double, so I can't see this compiling on your end anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have fewer than 309 digits after the dot your number is a whole number. The scientific notation must be confusing you, for example 1.234e+003 is also an integer because it's equal to 1234.

Comment: Ok..But then I want to make it as `1234`, how can it be done.?

Comment: It's just a representation of your floating point number. Try `string.Format("{0:0}",yourNumber)`. 
@Joni: '1.234e+003' is not an integer, but it can be both converted to and printed as an integer. ;-)

Comment: @Joni Is it just me or everyone is getting `Floating-point constant is outside the range of type decimal` error

Comment: @Joni Is `1.79769313486232E+308` equals to `$0` as someone told me that this number should be `$0`

Comment: What do you mean by *$0*? Are you working with regular expressions or money or what?

Comment: Well then no, a huge number like this is not equal to zero. If the result of a calculation should be 0 and gives you this number instead you have a huge mistake somewhere.

Comment: Ok..Thanks..For all your help..:)

Answer (score 1):

The nearest whole number is the same number you've tryed to round up; it has 309 digits:

```
  1.79769313486232E+308 == 1797693134862320000....00
```

"E+308" in scientific notation means "multply this by 10 in 308th power". A simple example:

1.234E+3 == 1.234 * Math.Pow(10, 3) == 1.234 * 1000 == 1234

You can easily convince yourself by printing out the number:

```
  BigInteger b = BigInteger.Parse("1.79769313486232E+308", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  Console.Write(b.ToString()); // <- 1797693134862320000....00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double.Parse("1.00E+4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

Add reference to  **System.Numerics** if you are Using **.NET framework 4.0**
 and then

```
 BigInteger b = BigInteger.Parse("1.79769313486232E+308", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```