# Represent very many decimals of an irrational number

Tags: c#, .net, math, decimal

I want to represent A LOT of decimal digits of a irrational number like sqrt(2) or cos(23).
For example i need to show the first 100,000 decimal digits of sqrt(2) , this is possible in c#?, how i can do this?

Comment: You're looking for a `BigDecimal` type.

Comment: It depends on the number - if you can find a taylor series or other method to calculate the number then yes, it's possible.  Not _simple_ but _possible_.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359372/is-there-a-bigfloat-class-in-c

Comment: with build in type? Nope. Custom calculation, yes. But whether you want to take it that far is another question

Comment: it is simple. go to wolframalpha and get everything you want. for example https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos+23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with the **GNU MPFR Library** , specifically with a [c# wrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.MPFR) by Luboš Hemala, then i code an algorithm for Nth roots.

```html
  public static void Nth_Root(ref StringBuilder Output,ref long ComaPos, String Radicand, String Index, ulong Precision,int NBase)
        {
            // (1 / Input Index) = N_Index
            Decimal D_index = Convert.ToDecimal(Index, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            D_index = 1.00m / D_index;
            String N_Index = D_index.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            //Calculating Precision
            Decimal Prec02 = Precision * 3.31125m;
            ulong Prec03 = Convert.ToUInt64(Prec02);
            int Prec04 = Convert.ToInt32(Precision);
            // Declaring MPFR Variables
            var Rad = new mpfr_struct();
            var Ind = new mpfr_struct();
            var Res = new mpfr_struct();
            MPFRLibrary.mpfr_init2(Rad, 1000LU);
            MPFRLibrary.mpfr_init2(Ind, 1000LU);
            MPFRLibrary.mpfr_init2(Res, Prec03);
            //String inputs to MPFR variables
            MPFRLibrary.mpfr_set_str(Rad, Radicand, 10, (int)Rounding.AwayFromZero);
            MPFRLibrary.mpfr_set_str(Ind, N_Index, 10, (int)Rounding.AwayFromZero);
            //Calculating Power of Radicand to the N_Index
            var sb = new StringBuilder(Prec04);
            long expptr = 0;
            MPFRLibrary.mpfr_pow(Res, Rad, Ind, (int)Rounding.AwayFromZero);
            //Converting MPFR Result to StringB
            MPFRLibrary.mpfr_get_str(sb, ref expptr, NBase, 0, Res, (int)Rounding.AwayFromZero);
            Output = sb;
            ComaPos = expptr;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK (please any reader correct me if I'm wrong) there's no built in type for that. However, as workarounds:

1. An [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813535/939213) with some system for it.
2. Use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) and do the rest yourself.
3. Use [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BigRational&referringTitle=Home) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359412/939213).