# any way of getting more than 13 decimal points in a double? C# or JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, double, decimal

is there any way i can get a double to contain more than default 13 (17 in JS) decimal points in C# or JS? 
Like a double with first 25 PI digits?

Comment: use Decimal then

Comment: Read the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.7.2.  You get what you get.  And, you can't represent everything you expect to represent (https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/).  The `decimal` type can get around some of this.

Comment: yes but all System.Math functions return a double. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @AndrejIlic: no, there are often overloads that take a `Decimal` and return one, for example [`Math.Ceiling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Ceiling_System_Decimal_). Only methods where it doesn't make sense to use `decimal` like [`Math.Asin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.asin?view=netframework-4.7.2) take only `double`.

Answer (score 1):

## Standard Data Types

Both the double in C# and he normal number data type in JavaScript is stored as 64 bit number, see
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp and
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm

This limits the number of decimal points that can be represented.
However, there are appropriate Libraries to handle this issue

## Possible Solutions

There are numerous libraries that handle large numbers and high precision floating point numbers.

- JavaScript
  see the answer here:
  [What is the standard solution in JavaScript for handling big numbers (BigNum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/what-is-the-standard-solution-in-javascript-for-handling-big-numbers-bignum).
- C#
  See the answers here: [Is there a BigFloat class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359372/is-there-a-bigfloat-class-in-c)