# Summing decimals

Tags: c#, math

In C#

```
(18761311001m * 0.36m + 
 18761311001m * 0.35m +
 18761311001m * 0.29m) 
/66.1445m 
=   283641285.38276047139217924393
```

But

```
((18761311001m * 0.36m)/66.1445m) + 
((18761311001m * 0.35m)/66.1445m) + 
((18761311001m * 0.29m) /66.1445m) 
= 283641285.38276047139217924392
```

Anyone know why the difference and how to get the same answer for both?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Also [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise)

Comment: What is your application doing where a sextillionth will make a difference?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the floating point math, since this is about *decimals*. The `decimal` type is not an IEEE 754 type. But there is surely a good duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @poke, IEEE754  has got decimal types, although the Microsoft implementation does not conform.  But of course, the principle behind the OPs problem is exactly the same.

Comment: @Atron Seige Won't make a difference so have now rounded the number to 20 (unit test)

Comment: While this isn't about floating point it is similar. Due to finite precision there will be rounding errors in intermediate results. Different operation will lead to different errors. So the results are – as with floating point – affected by the order of operations. Summary: finite representation has rounding errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decimal` has 28 significant digits. Your difference is at the 29th digit.

If you need more precision, you'll have to use an arbitrary-precision math library. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5738309/3764814) for some suggestions.