# how to get the BigInteger to the pow Double in C#?

Tags: c#, math, biginteger

I tried to use `BigInteger.Pow` method to calculate something like 10^12345.987654321 but this method only accept integer number as exponent like this:

> BigInteger.Pow(BigInteger x, int y)

so how can I use double number as exponent in above method?

Answer (score 5):

There's no arbitrary precision large number support in C#, so this cannot be done directly. There are some alternatives (such as looking for a 3rd party library), or you can try something like the code below - if the base is small enough, like in your case.

```
public class StackOverflow_11179289
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        int @base = 10;
        double exp = 12345.123;
        int intExp = (int)Math.Floor(exp);
        double fracExp = exp - intExp;
        BigInteger temp = BigInteger.Pow(@base, intExp);
        double temp2 = Math.Pow(@base, fracExp);
        int fractionBitsForDouble = 52;
        for (int i = 0; i < fractionBitsForDouble; i++)
        {
            temp = BigInteger.Divide(temp, 2);
            temp2 *= 2;
        }

        BigInteger result = BigInteger.Multiply(temp, (BigInteger)temp2);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

The idea is to use big integer math to compute the power of the integer part of the exponent, then use double (64-bit floating point) math to compute the power of the fraction part. Then, using the fact that

```
a ^ (int + frac) = a ^ int * a ^ frac
```

we can combine the two values into a single big integer. But simply converting the double value to a BigInteger would lose a lot of its precision, so we first "shift" the precision onto the bigInteger (using the loop above, and the fact that the `double` type uses 52 bits for the precision), then multiplying the result.

Notice that the result is an approximation, if you want a more precise number, you'll need a library that does arbitrary precision floating point math.

**Update**: If the base / exponent are small enough that the power would be in the range of `double`, we can simply do what Sebastian Piu suggested (`new BigInteger(Math.Pow((double)@base, exp))`)

Comment: I'm just asking out of curiosity, why isn't doing new `new BigInteger(Math.Pow(10, 123.123));` correct?

Comment: He wanted to do 10 ^ **12345.123**, which would be beyond the range of double (result of Math.Pow). I reduced it so I could see the result in my console app, but I'll increase it again to be clear.

Comment: Then you'll need a 3rd-party library. This does not exist in the core .NET Framework.

Comment: @carlosfigueira did you know any 3rd-party library which can solve this problem?

Comment: No. You can leave this question open waiting for more answers, but there have been others around here (such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/621684/751090, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2863388/751090), and the one answer which pointed to a library has a broken link.

Comment: Interesting! But you don't have to do the "precision transfer" in a loop. You could use a constant "2 to the 52nd power" (or 53rd, maybe even better) that can be represented exactly as a `Double` and as a `BigInteger`. Then divide `temp` once by this constant, and multiply `temp2` once by this constant.

Answer (score 2):

I like carlosfigueira's answer, but of course the result of his method can only be correct on the first (most significant) 15-17 digits, because a `System.Double` is used as a multiplier eventually.

It is interesting to note that there does exist a method `BigInteger.Log` that performs the "inverse" operation. So if you want to calculate `Pow(7, 123456.78)` you could, in theory, search all `BigInteger` numbers `x` to find one number such that `BigInteger.Log(x, 7)` is equal to `123456.78` or closer to `123456.78` than any other `x` of type `BigInteger`.

Of course the logarithm function is increasing, so your search can use some kind of "binary search" (bisection search). Our answer lies between `Pow(7, 123456)` and `Pow(7, 123457)` which can both be calculated exactly.

**Skip the rest if you want**

Now, how can we predict in advance if there are more than one integer whose logarithm is `123456.78`, up to the precision of `System.Double`, or if there is in fact no integer whose logarithm hits that specific `Double` (the precise result of an ideal `Pow` function being an irrational number)? In our example, there will be very many integers giving the same `Double` `123456.78` because the factor `m = Pow(7, epsilon)` (where `epsilon` is the smallest positive number such that `123456.78 + epilon` has a representation as a `Double` different from the representation of `123456.78` itself) is big enough that there will be very many integers between the true answer and the true answer multiplied by `m`.

Remember from calculus that the derivative of the mathemtical function `x → Pow(7, x)` is `x → Log(7)*Pow(7, x)`, so the slope of the graph of the exponential function in question will be `Log(7)*Pow(7, 123456.78)`. This number multiplied by the above `epsilon` is still much much greater than one, so there are many integers satisfying our need.

Actually, I think carlosfigueira's method will give a "correct" answer `x` in the sense that `Log(x, 7)` has the same representation as a `Double` as `123456.78` has. But has anyone tried it? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide another answer that is hopefully more clear. The point is: **Since the precision of `System.Double` is limited to approx. 15-17 decimal digits, the result of any `Pow(BigInteger, Double)` calculation will have an even more limited precision.** Therefore, there's no hope of doing better than carlosfigueira's answer does.

Let me illustrate this with an example. Suppose we wanted to calculate

```
Pow(10, exponent)
```

where in this example I choose for `exponent` the double-precision number

```
const double exponent = 100.0 * Math.PI;
```

This is of course only an example. The value of `exponent`, in decimal, can be given as one of

```
314.159265358979
314.15926535897933
314.1592653589793258106510620564222335815429687500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
```

The first of these numbers is what you normally see (15 digits). The second version is produced with `exponent.ToString("R")` and contains 17 digits. Note that the precision of `Double` is less than 17 digits. The third representation above is the theoretical "exact" value of `exponent`. Note that this differs, of course, from the mathematical number 100π near the 17th digit.

To figure out what `Pow(10, exponent)` ought to be, I simply did `BigInteger.Log10(x)` on a lot of numbers `x` to see how I could reproduce `exponent`. So the results presented here simply reflect the .NET Framework's implementation of `BigInteger.Log10`.

It turns out that any `BigInteger x` from

```
0x0C3F859904635FC0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
through
0x0C3F85990481FE7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

makes `Log10(x)` equal to `exponent` to the precision of 15 digits. Similarly, any number from

```
0x0C3F8599047BDEC0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
through
0x0C3F8599047D667FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

satisfies `Log10(x) == exponent` to the precision of `Double`. Put in another way, *any* number from the latter range is equally "correct" as the result of `Pow(10, exponent)`, simply because the precision of `exponent` is so limited.

*(Interlude: The bunches of `0`s and `F`s reveal that .NET's implementation only considers the most significant bytes of `x`. They don't care to do better, precisely because the `Double` type has this limited precision.)*

Now, the only reason to introduce third-party software, would be if you **insist** that `exponent` is to be interpreted as the third of the decimal numbers given above. (It's really a miracle that the `Double` type allowed you to specify exactly the number you wanted, huh?) In that case, the result of `Pow(10, exponent)` would be an irrational (but algebraic) number with a tail of never-repeating decimals. It couldn't fit in an integer without rounding/truncating. PS! If we take the exponent to be the real number 100π, the result, mathematically, would be different: some transcendental number, I suspect.