# .NET - What data type to use for a very big decimal number?

Tags: c#, .net, types, numbers, decimal

I'm looking for some data type what to use in C# .NET for storing very big decimal number in range <0;1) eg. 1000 decimals (as much as possible, the more is better). I will need to use this number for basic mathematical operations (+, -, *, /, <, >). Data type `decimal` is too small for me. I know `BigInteger`, but it is not for decimal number and it's operations.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just use BigDecimal and put a "0." at the front.

Or build your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arbitrary precision decimals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621684/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the BCL for it.

However, I've found a custom built type that looks quite interesting called BigFloat.  I've had a scan through the code and it looks quite good.  It takes a BigInteger as the denominator so that should give you much greater accuracy.

It also covers your add, subtract, multiplation and so on.  It even goes into square root/logarithms etc.

Here it is:  https://github.com/Osinko/BigFloat

I'd take a look and see if it fits your purpose, there's an example in the repository.